# R ggplot different colours in title label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can draw a chart in `ggplot` and add a title:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot <- ggplot(PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight)) + geom_boxplot()
plot
plot <- plot+ ggtitle("red label\nblue label")
plot
```

But how can I change the colors in the title, so the first part of the title is in red color and the second part in blue color?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Here's a post on how to do this in base graphics: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/01/multicolor-text-in-r.html . I think there might be an analogous grid graphics solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to an [old google groups page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/54q_qdTE1L0):

```
print(plot, vp=viewport(height=0.8))
grid.text(0.5, unit(1,"npc") - unit(1,"line"), 
          label="Red text\n",
          gp=gpar(col="red"))
grid.text(0.5, unit(1,"npc") - unit(1,"line"), 
          label="\nBlue text",
          gp=gpar(col="blue"))
```

[image]